# Undefined variable: sub inside the foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Controller:

```
public function dashboard()
{
    $course = Course::all();
    return view('content.dashboard',compact('course'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($course as $year)

    $sub = \App\Models\SubCourse::where('course_id',$year->id)->first();
    @dd($sub->id);

@endforeach
```

In the above code I am trying to get value of `SubCourse` but it throw an error i.e. `Undefined variable: sub (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\example\resources\views\content\dashboard.blade.php)`. I don't know why? Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: You cannot define variables inside foreach loops on the view.

Comment: The view is for displaying the data and shouldn't be fetching new data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You Can Accessing Model Like this  in PHP Tag

```
@foreach($course as $year)
   <?php
     $sub = \App\Models\SubCourse::where('course_id',$year->id)->first();
     @dd($sub->id);
    ?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @arsha I think you got your answer

Comment: This code is bad, works, but its bad. If the user changes the ID of the course to any available in the database, it would show regardless. Adding the PHP code in regards to the guard on the view is def something that should not be done. There is no point in adding a whole new block of PHP code in the view when you can do this through a controller, AND should be done in the controller.

Comment: @DanielL it's just an example of arsha 's problem. how to show data in the blade file. and I can't change all code that is wrote down by others and I can't force anyone to follow coding standards it's not my duty here right we together get a solution to the problem. not to demotivate or disrespect people. you should cheer up arsha to learn new things.